# How to check if a Gmail label has a nested sub-label?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Using Google Apps Script, is there a function to check if a Gmail label has nested sub-labels? If a label has one or more sub-labels I want to exclude them from a code sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct method to get labels from a "parent" label but this is quite simple to get using the simple `getUserLabels()` method [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getUserLabels()) and illustrated by the following small code :

```
function getAllLabels(){
  var results = [];
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("label: " + labels[i].getName());
    results.push(labels[i].getName());
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if(results[i].indexOf('/')>0){Logger.log(results[i]+' has a subLabel')};
  }
}
```

This will show a list of all your labels and from the second loop you'll get  a list of all Labels that have at least one sub-Label.

Note that this script has to be improved because it will consider *INBOX* (for example but not only) as a label which is not really what you want but that part will be easy to manage with a few conditions.

Comment: There would be some revision required if the OP needed to track sublabels of a sublabel in this instance, but largely this is a functional solution. I'd be tempted to use a results object with labels and sublabels handled as properties etc. For reuse, but that's possibly overkill.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, I choose the string approach to make it as simple as possible and, as mentioned in the answer, didn't bring a "final" solution, more like a direction on how to get it simply. But now tht you mention it I might give the properties approach a try ;-) thx !!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can create labels containing / in the name without any nesting involved. e.g. Create a label "Foo/bar" and it will show at the top-level as is - no nesting indication whatsoever. I'm currently trying to find out how to tell the difference between nested relationship and a literal / in the name.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this is not a "final" solution. The case you imagine could be detected checking if the / separated sublabels exist... well, I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I added something to it so that all sublabels are displayed

```
   function getAllLabels(){
  var results = [];
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("  Label: " + labels[i].getName());
    results.push(labels[i].getName());
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if(results[i].indexOf('/')>0){Logger.log('️ Sub Label: '+results[i])};
  }
}

function processSubLabels(label, prefix) {
  var subLabels = label.getLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < subLabels.length; i++) {
    var subLabelName = prefix + "/" + subLabels[i].getName();
    Logger.log("subLabel: " + subLabelName);
    processSubLabels(subLabels[i], subLabelName);
  }
}
```