# Get all sub-labels of a Gmail label through a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I would like to get all child labels of a given parent label. Is it possible?

In [How to check if a Gmail label has a nested sub-label?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30012268) it is checked whether all labels have a sub-label, and I tried doing something similar for an specific one, but with no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent-child relation of Gmail labels is based on their names: it you have a label "foo/bar" and there is also a label named "foo", then the former is considered a child of the latter. (I just tested this by manually creating "foo/bar" label and then "foo"; as soon as "foo" appeared, it acquired "bar" as a child.)

So, the following function will return the list of all labels that are children of the given label. (The argument `parent` here is a label itself, not its name).

```
function children(parent) { 
  var name = parent.getName() + '/';
  return GmailApp.getUserLabels().filter(function(label) {
    return label.getName().slice(0, name.length) == name;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thankz!! Now, to get the "grandchildren", do i use the loop again on the children labels?

Comment: Yes, you can repeat the process; for example, by calling the same function again. Something like `children('foo').map(children).reduce(function (a,b) {return a.concat(b);});`